# Как расширить том с Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Здраствуйте! Рядом с Windows 10 поставил Ubuntu 22.04, но выделил на него всего-лишь 50 ГБ памяти. Ее быстро стало не хватать. Как можно безопасно расширить том с Ubuntu, ничего не сломав?

Comment: Как у вас создан раздел под Linux? Если LVM, то там не сложно. В интернете полно статей

Comment: Просто расширьте (если есть куда) и всё, линуксы от такого не ломаются (даже без LVM). А если расширять некуда — покажите текущую разметку диска, а там посмотрим

Answer (score 1):

с помощью [gparted](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=ru), есть практически на любом live дистрибутиве, главное не прерывать процесс переразметки, сначала уменьшить размер какого либо раздела, а потом на освободившееся место расширить ubuntu

без переразметки попробовать:
sudo apt-get clean и sudo apt-get autoclean могут очистить кэш пакетов, которые накопились во время обновлений, может освободиться довольно много места

[filelight](https://blog.sedicomm.com/2019/11/27/filelight-bystryj-analiz-ispolzovaniya-diska-v-linux/) покажет чем занято место на диске